# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"statics"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error.

[image]

```
<%= link_to "New Product", 
new_static_path %>
```

## statics Controller

```
class StaticsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @products = Product.all
end

def new
    @product = Product.new
end

def show
    product_value = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product_attribute = ProductAttribute.where(value: product_value.value)
end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    Product.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
    redirect_to root_url
end

private

    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name,:value)
    end
```

end

## Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing the products in home page</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li><%=link_to product.name, static_path(product) %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Edit", edit_static_path(product) %></li>
<% end %>
```

## ROUTES.RB

```
root 'statics#index'
resources :statics
resources :products
resources :productattributes
```

## Rake routes

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
                 root GET    /                                     statics#index
              statics GET    /statics(.:format)                    statics#index
                      POST   /statics(.:format)                    statics#create
           new_static GET    /statics/new(.:format)                statics#new
          edit_static GET    /statics/:id/edit(.:format)           statics#edit
               static GET    /statics/:id(.:format)                statics#show
                      PATCH  /statics/:id(.:format)                statics#update
                      PUT    /statics/:id(.:format)                statics#update
                      DELETE /statics/:id(.:format)                statics#destroy
             products GET    /products(.:format)                   products#index
                      POST   /products(.:format)                   products#create
          new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)               products#new
         edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)          products#edit
              product GET    /products/:id(.:format)               products#show
                      PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)               products#update
                      PUT    /products/:id(.:format)               products#update
                      DELETE /products/:id(.:format)               products#destroy

     productattributes GET /productattributes(.:format)   productattributes#index

POST   /productattributes(.:format)     productattributes#create

new_productattribute  GET    /productattributes/new(.:format)      productattributes#new

edit_productattribute GET    /productattributes/:id/edit(.:format) productattributes#edit

productattribute      GET    /productattributes/:id(.:format)      productattributes#show

 PATCH  /productattributes/:id(.:format)      productattributes#update

 PUT    /productattributes/:id(.:format)      productattributes#update

  DELETE /productattributes/:id(.:format)      productattributes#destroy
```

this is the rake routes for the project.

Comment: i made those changes you suggested, yet its not accepting statics_path, its suggesting static_path.@widjajayd

Comment: I just change my answer to follow your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your software little bit different with rails way
probably this can help, if you don't want to use different model with controller name

change your routes.rb as follow

```
resources :products, path: "statics"
```

Comment: Cant i direct it to statics controller's path.@widjajayd

Comment: i'm sorry for bothering you, but i'm still stuck with the same error.

Comment: ok please after you change your routes.rb please restart rails server command

Comment: yea even after that, i'm not seeing any change.

Comment: You need an id when accessing `show`. Your url should be something like this: http://your_host:3000/statics/show/34 assuming 34 is the id of the object you want to display (and that you have a corresponding one in the database).

Comment: Can you run the following command `rake routes` in CLI and add the output to the description of the question (this can help confirming my answer or point to something else)

Comment: iv'e added the rake routes result, please take a look

Comment: i think i figured it out after i reverted with git. this occurs if i delete the parent model without deleting the dependent. Thanks a lot widjajayd and @Stephane Paquet. Have a nice day!. Sorry for bothering you both.